# Is it riba (a major sin) to have a mortgage from before I converted to Islam?

Tags: riba, conversion, mortgage

Bought a house over 10 yrs ago on mortgage. I became a Muslim several months ago. I know riba is haram but I cannot sell the house because the other co-owners do not want to sell. I also signed a 2nd mortgage because the co-owners needed to close old debt account. If I didn't sign, the 2nd mortgage would not be approved. I don't have anywhere else to live for now. I repented but is it enough as riba is major sin?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help] and feel free to check our [meta] to learn more about this site and how it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Remember Allah is most gracious most merciful, people like to see Allah as a God of punishment. He has no gain in punishing anyone other than to enforce justice or to straighten a person out.

In your case Allah most high is delighted you found Islam and guided you regardless of what ever you were doing before.

Allah knows that you and your situations won't change over night but your  now your actively conscious about your behaviour.

If you have any control in the situation without too much loss then go for it.  Avoid the Riba. If you don't have any control and there may involve a lot of loss. Then I would say be conscious about it and ask Allah to find you a way out. But don't fall into shaytarns trap of thinking that the sin is so bad Allah won't forgive it.